# Visual Studio 2019: Find and Replace does not search *.sql by default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2019, the global **Find and Replace** functionality no longer searches the .sql files! How can I add *.sql to search file types?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the default exclude:

[image]

That searches *.sql files for me.